# SPFx: pnp search by managed properties

Tags: search, spfx, pnp, managed-property

I made a simple pnp search in SPFx by Querytext, now I need to make search by managed properties.

I have text managed property RefinersTextListOWSTEXT

So far I made this:

```
const _results: ISearchResult[] = [];
    return new Promise<ISearchResult[]>((resolve, reject) => {
        pnp.sp.search({
            Querytext: query,
            RowLimit: 20,
            StartRow: 0,
            SelectProperties: ["Title","Author","Path","FileType","RefinersTextList"]
        })
            .then((results) => {
                results.PrimarySearchResults.forEach((result) => {
                    _results.push({
                        title: result.Title,
                        description: result.HitHighlightedSummary,
                        link: result.Path,
                        author: result.Author,
                        filetype: result.FileType
                    });
                });
            })
            .then(
                () => { resolve(_results); }
            )
            .catch(
                () => { reject(new Error("Error")); }
            );
    });
```

Comment: Use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) which shows how to query based on managed property and then you just need to pass this query in **QueryText**

Comment: Now it's working! I get rid of all properties in **SelectProperties** and left only **RefinersTextList**. Now I get search only by managed properties

Comment: Great. Can I ask you to put how you did it in the "Your Answer" section below, and mark your own answer as an answer? The idea is to let everyone know too if they face the same issue like yours.